# Adding fields to the media uploader with jquery listeners

Tags: jquery, media-library, media-modal, backbone

So I have the code to successfully add a select field to my media uploader (gallery view) which is cool, but I also need to add some jquery listeners to that field.

I'm using the 'print_media_templates' hook to add my markup and js, and 
I want to add a jQuery listener to the select field, `.js--gallery-style`, which would toggle another field with show or whatever:

```
function add_gallery_type_option(){


  ?>
  <script type="text/html" id="tmpl-my-custom-gallery-setting">
    <label class="setting">
      <span><?php _e('Gallery Style'); ?></span>
      <select class="js--gallery-style" data-setting="gallery_style">
        <option value="default"> Grid (default) </option>
        <option value="slider"> Slider </option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </script>

  <script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){


      _.extend(wp.media.gallery.defaults, {
        my_custom_attr: 'default_val'
      });

      // merge default gallery settings template with yours
      wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery = wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery.extend({
        template: function(view){
          return wp.media.template('gallery-settings')(view)
               + wp.media.template('my-custom-gallery-setting')(view);
        }
      });

    });

  </script>
  <?php
}
add_action('print_media_templates', 'add_gallery_type_option');
```

I'm sure this is pretty easy but I havent learned backbone.js yet so I dont know where to start looking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Blackbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-130) website:

> render is the core function that your view should override, in order
>   to populate its element (this.el), with the appropriate HTML. The
>   convention is for render to always return this.

So, I have modified the code a little bit to add jQuery change listener.

```
function add_gallery_type_option(){
  ?>
  <script type="text/html" id="tmpl-my-custom-gallery-setting">
    <label class="setting">
      <span><?php _e('Gallery Style'); ?></span>
      <select class="js--gallery-style" data-setting="gallery_style">
        <option value="default"> Grid (default) </option>
        <option value="slider"> Slider </option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </script>

  <script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      _.extend(wp.media.gallery.defaults, {
        my_custom_attr: 'default_val'
      });

      // merge default gallery settings template with yours
      wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery = wp.media.view.Settings.Gallery.extend({
        template: function(view){
          return wp.media.template('gallery-settings')(view)
               + wp.media.template('my-custom-gallery-setting')(view);
        },
        render: function() {
                wp.media.View.prototype.render.apply( this, arguments );

                jQuery(this.$('.js--gallery-style')).change(function(e)
                  {
                      alert(jQuery(this).val());
                  })
                return this;
            }
      });

    });

  </script>
  <?php
}
add_action('print_media_templates', 'add_gallery_type_option');
```