# Get Thumbnails and Thumbnails URL from Media Manager

Tags: post-thumbnails, media

I need to insert several thumbnails generated from featured images in html, to use them in a slider that I've built. I can't get the thumbnail size via PHP because it breaks the code module (I am using DIVI, a premium theme) and I would like to find the URL from the media manager, or other site.

Comment: There's several functions to do this, but we might need to see the code you have so far to recommend the best way to do it in your situation.  Keep in mind third party themes are off topic here - we can help you do this but not if your theme prevents it.

Comment: Hit @TimMalone It isn't about functions, I can only use HTML in this case and would like to get the media-links easily from the media manager. - With functions would be much easier but I can't use PHP. BTW it is not about third party themes, I am trying to get an information from the WordPress Media.

Comment: Why can't you use PHP? I don't think you're going to be able to do this in HTML...

Comment: @TimMalone I can't because I am using DIVI theme code module and it doesn't allow PHP. Why I am using DIVI theme? **Because my customer wants it, something easy to modify with drag and drop capabilities**. That's why I'm trying to get the thumbnail links from the mediagallery. BTW it isn't offtopic, I asked for something specific related with the media manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you need to show the image url to the user, for all sizes, within the *Attachment Details* screen.

### Using Underscore/Backbone

We can extend the *Attachment Details View*, in a similar fashion as in my previous answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/206179/26350) and based on the media views in the core:

```
<!-- Custom template part -->
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-wpse-url-per-size">
    <div class="wpse-url-per-size" style="padding-top:5px; clear:both;">
        <h2>Show URL Per Image Size</h2>
        <label class="setting">
            <span>Size</span>
            <select id="wpse-select">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <# _.each( data.sizes, function ( item, size) { #>
                    <option value="{{item.url}}">{{size}} {{item.width}}x{{item.height}} 
                <# } ) #>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label class="setting">
            <span>URL</span>
            <input type="text" id="wpse-url" readonly>
        </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

and

```
<!-- Extend the Attachment Details View -->
<script>
jQuery(document).ready( function($) 
{   
    var m = wp.media;       

    m.view.Settings.AttachmentDisplay = m.view.Settings.AttachmentDisplay.extend(
    {
        template: function(view){
            return m.template('attachment-display-settings')(view)
            + m.template('wpse-url-per-size')(
                {sizes: this.options.attachment.get('sizes')}
            );
        },
        events: _.defaults( 
            m.view.Settings.AttachmentDisplay.prototype.events, 
            { 'change #wpse-select': 'wpse_change' }
        ),
        wpse_change: function(e){
            this.$( "#wpse-url" ).val( this.$('#wpse-select').val() );
        }       
    } );
} );
</script>
```

This is then hooked into the `print_media_templates` action.

Here we don't need to override the `render()` method, as done [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/196533/26350) by @kalimah-apps, since we override the `events()` method instead.

The available image sizes can be filtered through the `image_size_names_choose` filter, where the default ones are *thumbnail*, *medium*, *large* and *full*.

Here's an example:

[image: url per size]

### Using the `attachment_fields_to_edit` filter

We can e.g. create a custom *form field* with a *select box* and a readonly *input text*, via the `attachment_fields_to_edit` filter, to display the image url for each image size:

[image: all image sizes]

[image]

Here's a demo plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Show Image URL For All Image Sizes
 * Description: Show the image url,  for all image sizes, under the 'Attachment Details'
 * Plugin URI:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/232404/26350
 * Text Domain: wpse-url-per-size
 * Version:     1.0.0
 */

add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', function( $form_fields, $post )
{
    // Nothing to do if the attachment isn't an image
    if( ! wp_attachment_is( 'image', $post ) )
        return $form_fields;

    // First option
    $options = sprintf( 
        '<option value="">%s</option>',
        esc_html__( 'Select', 'wpse-image-size-url' )
    );

    // Generate options for all image sizes
    foreach( (array) get_intermediate_image_sizes() as $size )
    {
        // Fetch image url, width and height for the given size
        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post->ID, $size );

        if( ! is_array( $src ) )
            continue;

        // Generate a single option's value    
        $value = sprintf( 
            '%s %dx%d',
            esc_html( $size ),
            $src[1],
            $src[2]
        );

        // Generate HTML for a single option
        $options .= sprintf( 
            '<option value="%s">%s</option>',
            esc_url( $src[0] ),
            $value
        );

    }

    // Generate HTML for the select box and input text
    $html = sprintf(
        '<select id="wpse-image-sizes" >%s</select>
         <input type="text" id="wpse-image-url" readonly>',
        $options
    );  

    // Handle the select box change
    $html .= '<script>
        (function($){
            $( "#wpse-image-sizes" ).on( "change", function(e) {
                $( "#wpse-image-url" ).val( this.value );
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>';

    // Setup our custom form field
    $form_fields['wpse-image-sizes'] = [
        'label' => esc_html__( 'URL Per Size', 'wpse-url-per-size' ),
        'input' => 'html',
        'html' => $html,
    ];

    return $form_fields;

}, 10, 2 );
```

### Using the `media_meta` filter

This would be similar as the `attachment_fields_to_edit` example, but displayed within the meta info and without the form fields setup.